# how does id, groups, work?

Tags: ubuntu, login

Well, I have a problem with my username and password login.

It seems like my system not recognize the username, password, groups.
I also use nscd as well to see how is the process, but still it's confusing.

I have checked /etc/passwd, /etc/shadow and /etc/groups also, and it seems normal.

this is the log of `id` command and nscd :

```
 id
7851: handle_request: request received (Version = 2) from PID 8038
7851:   GETFDPW
7851: provide access to FD 8, for passwd
7851: handle_request: request received (Version = 2) from PID 8038
7851:   GETPWBYUID (0)
7851: Haven't found "0" in password cache!
7851: add new entry "0" of type GETPWBYUID for passwd to cache (first)
7851: handle_request: request received (Version = 2) from PID 8038
7851:   GETFDGR
7851: provide access to FD 10, for group
7851: handle_request: request received (Version = 2) from PID 8038
7851:   GETGRBYGID (0)
7851: Haven't found "0" in group cache!
7851: add new entry "0" of type GETGRBYGID for group to cache (first)
uid=0 gid=0 groups=0
```

And this is with groups command

```
 groups
7851: handle_request: request received (Version = 2) from PID 8048
7851:   GETFDPW
7851: provide access to FD 8, for passwd
7851: handle_request: request received (Version = 2) from PID 8048
7851:   GETPWBYUID (0)
7851: Haven't found "0" in password cache!
7851: add new entry "0" of type GETPWBYUID for passwd to cache (first)
7851: handle_request: request received (Version = 2) from PID 8048
7851:   GETFDGR
7851: provide access to FD 10, for group
id: cannot find name for group ID 0
0
I have no name!@morningboy-desktop:/#
```

I also face "I have no name!" in my login prompt.

So How is it ?

Comment: What operating system are you using? Is this behavior something you've seen before, or something which just started happening? Do you think it's possible that somebody has tinkered with your system without you noticing? The "I have no name!" thing seems a bit fishy.

Comment: I am using ubuntu. maybe there's someone who change the configuration file. do you know how the system load the files that is related with administration ?. such as /etc/passwd, /etc/shadow, /etc/groups etc. 

I am sure we can make it work if we know how it's work in detail.

Comment: You should try disabling nscd so as to see if it is the cause of your problem. Do you use a remote user database such as NIS or LDAP? Other useful information would be the line corresponding to your user in /etc/passwd, and the passwd and shadow lines in /etc/nsswitch.conf.

Answer (score 0):

[This post says](http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=362966):

> the administrator id (from Samba) was
>   somehow assigned a low uid, one that
>   was in use by an id with a shorter
>   name.
>
> moving administrator to an unused uid
>   seems to have solved the issue

And [this post suggests](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/glibc/+bug/302724) nscd is crashing, causing this issue. The last reply there suggests a workaround by switching over to unscd. Might be worth looking into those.

Comment: I don't think nscd in my case is crash. nscd told us that they don't find any data in password cache or group cache. well I don't know really know what happen. do you know, where do nscd read the cache ?